# Python Module To Detect Linux Distro Version

Tags: python, redhat, suse

Is there an existing python module that can be used to detect which distro of Linux and which version of the distro is currently installed.

For example:

- RedHat Enterprise 5
- Fedora 11
- Suse Enterprise 11
- etc....

I can make my own module by parsing various files like /etc/redhat-release but I was wondering if a module already exists?

Cheers,
Ivan

Comment: related http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92199/how-can-i-reliably-get-the-operating-systems-name

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Look up the docs for the platform module: http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html

Example:

```
>>> platform.uname()
('Linux', 'localhost', '2.6.31.5-desktop-1mnb', '#1 SMP Fri Oct 23 00:05:22 EDT 2009', 'x86_64', 'AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 3600+')
>>> platform.linux_distribution()
('Mandriva Linux', '2010.0', 'Official')
```

Comment: Both functions are deprecated

Comment: Not sure that uname is, but linux_distribution definitely is, details -> https://bugs.python.org/issue1322

Answer (score 3):

I've written a package called `distro` (now used by `pip`) which aims to replace `distro.linux_distribution`. It works on many distributions which might return weird or empty tuples when using `platform`.

https://github.com/nir0s/distro (`distro`, on pypi)

It provides a much more elaborate API to retrieve distribution related information.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov  7 2016, 11:55:55) 
[GCC 6.2.1 20160830] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import distro
>>> distro.linux_distribution()
(u'Antergos Linux', '', u'ARCHCODE')
```

By the way, `platform.linux_distribution` is to be removed in Python 3.7.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer doesn't work on RHEL 5.x. The quickest way is on a redhat-like system is to read and look at the /etc/redhat-release file. This file is updated every time you run an update and the system gets upgraded by a minor release number.

```
$ python
>>> open('/etc/redhat-release','r').read().split(' ')[6].split('.')
['5', '5']
```

If you take the split parts out it will just give you string. No module like you asked, but I figured it was short and elegant enough that you may find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the best way, but I used subprocess to execute 'uname -v' and then looked for the distro name in the output.

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(['uname','-v'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout = process.communicate()[0]
distro = format(stdout).rstrip("\n")

if 'FreeBSD' in distro:
   print "It's FreeBSD"
elif 'Ubuntu' in distro:
   print "It's Ubuntu"
elif 'Darwin' in distro:
   print "It's a Mac"
else:
   print "Unknown distro"
```